# MediaElement.js - Multiple players, can't play videos after one player has already started playing one

Tags: php, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to track down a tricky issue with MediaElement.js players. I'm using the player in multiple locations on a page, all of which are video files. These video files all point to the same url, which is a file download script that streams the file given an id. Each file has a unique id, which means the url given to the MediaElement player is of the type "/fileDownload.php?fileId={some file id}"

When I press play on one of the videos, it loads fine and starts streaming the video. However, when I pause the video and try to play another one of the videos, it won't load them at all, and will just spin forever like it's loading them. The videos won't play until the page is refreshed.

I'm not tremendously familiar with the implementation of the MediaElement players. Is it possible this occurs because MediaElement.js can't handle files coming from the same URL but with different GET parameters?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the execution of your JS ? As long as the {some file id} changes it should not be a ploblem You need to post at least part of your code in order to get help. MediaElement player is really badly documented, the instructions are for JS gurus not mortals like you and me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I actually figured out that my problem was something different than I thought (as is often the case!). Basically, I was using a backend PHP script to stream the content, and the sessions were locking each time it would stream, so nothing else would be able to play until that session got unlocked. I was able to fix it, so things are working now. Thanks!